# Ethernet Cable with red and yellow wires

Tags: networking, ethernet, cable

I have an ethernet cable with a strange color pattern. This cable has the standard yellow, blue and brown wires. However, there is also a red and a yellow wire, as well as three completely white wires. The wires were not twisted, so I don't know which of them are pairs.

It also has an "naked" copper wire between the insulated colored wires. There are also two fabric-like strings inside the wire.

How do I connect these wires according to the A or B wiring standard? And is it even an ethernet cable?

Comment: You don't, since that's not an Ethernet cable.

Comment: I am pretty sure it is. It is already connected to a socket on the other side, which was done by a professional. If it is indeed not an ethernet cable, what is it then?

Comment: sounds like a phone cable, old style PBX. Not twisted pair, not Ethernet.

Comment: Can you post a picture of it?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a picture right now. Will post it tomorrow when I'm back there.

Comment: anyway, Ethernet isn't even yellow, blue, brown; it's orange blue brown green + striped versions.

Comment: @Tetsujin I think you might be right, but the yellow, blue, red, brown, etc makes it sound like it's part of an 25-pair coded wire. Except those have twist, so I'm not really sure what it is without seeing it.

Comment: @DrZoo - yup, I'm guessing a bit - my only certainty is "it's not ethernet as we know it, Jim" ;)

Comment: I added some information to my post maybe it helps you guys to identify the cable :)

Comment: I can picture it, but I'm struggling to remember what it's for. The nylon strings are to give you easy-strip of the outer sheath, pull to rip down the side, then clip off the spare.

Comment: If the wires aren't twisted, it's not useful for ethernet.

Answer (score 2):

If your question is just about how A/B wiring works: Most of the times, stick to T568A. For further information see [this Link or google T568a/b wiring](https://www.cableorganizer.com/telecom-datacom/connectors.htm).

**About figuring out the wires:**

I've dealt with such old cable messes in the past. There are two directions to choose from.

The "hacky" approach:

Check if the "bundling" is identical on both sides. if there is always the same coating-color next to each other you can map the white ones out (white between blue+red for example) for yourself and use the cable. If its different patterns on each side you have to short circuit and do continuity testing on the other end to map them. *hint: its smarter to have a bystander with a meter and you just drill wires together on your end and then directly fix them to matching positions.*

I had to run a similar cable for networking for quite a while the best speeds i got out of it were 10 MBit/s declared and ~4 MBit/s measured, caused by the interferences.

The best practice:

It would be to just replace with a Cat 6a or later Ethernet-Cable and enjoy the lightning fast networking! Remember to switch the connectors accordingly. If you got no punch down tools for krone/LSA connectors you might want to look for tool-less solutions like [this](https://sgcdn.startech.com/005329/media/products/gallery_large/KEYSTONE2WH.C.jpg).

Answer (score 1):

That ain't ethernet and isn't usable as ethernet.
For ethernet the pairs must be twisted or else you get 10 Mb/s (at best) over a meter (maybe 2 meters).

The color-scheme is really odd. You sure those 2 yellows and 3 whites are really identical? Sometimes identical colored wires have a thin stripe or a colored dot every few centimeters to make it possible to tell them apart.

It sorts of sounds like you have an old DecConnect serial cable from the 80's. Various color-schemes were used for those back then.
I've seen some of those that used light and dark yellow and all 3 the whites were grounds. If it is DecConnect the cable is so old that the 2 yellows may have faded to nearly the same color.